# What do you mean by block numbers in an inode?

Tags: c, system

Question:

Suppose an I-node can hold 7 direct block pointers and a single-indirect block pointer. If a block size is 4KB, and there are 32-bit block numbers, what is the largest file supported by the system?

Answer:

7 direct blocks, 4KB in size

Indirect block points to 4K/4 = 1024 blocks, each block 4KB in size

1031 * 4K = 4222976B = 4124KB ~ 4.03MB

Typically nowadays, inodes have:

12 direct block pointers

1 singly indirect pointer

1 doubly indirect pointer

1 triply indirect pointer

<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< My understanding >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

I understand that an inode has 7 direct and 1 indirect block pointer and each block pointer has 4kb size.and when it says that there are 32-bit block number, does that mean that there are more 1024 block pointes there?

Comment: On which filesystem type? zfs, extfs, ufs, etc.?

Comment: Unix filesystes

Comment: @Raveel All the FS mentionned by Alexandre are Unix file systems.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the problem you have? What is it you don't understand? You do understand the concept of "indirect pointers"?

Comment: I don't understand your doubt, your uncertainty.

Comment: i dont understand this part of the calculation: Indirect block points to 4K/4 = 1024 blocks, each block 4KB in size

Comment: A single indirect pointer points to a data block on the disk. This data block contains pointers to other data blocks. Each block on the disk is 4096 bytes (4kB). The size of each pointer is 4 bytes (32 bits is 4 bytes). Then that means the indirect block have space for the blocksize (4096) divided by 4 (the size of each pointer). I.e. 4096 / 4, which is equal to 1024. In other words an indirect block-block pointer block have space for 1024 pointers to other data block.

Comment: Perhaps you need [an illustration](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Ext2-inode.gif)? (And there are [***many*** more](https://www.google.se/search?q=inode+indirect+block+pointers&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&biw=1920&bih=1091))

Comment: thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

If the block size is 4 kiB and you have 32 bit (4 byte) block numbers, you can have 1024 such block numbers in one block. (I think this is the part you did not understand.) That means: Each of the 32 bit numbers uses 4 bytes of the block, thus 1024 of these numbers use 4096 bytes = exactly 1 block. So 1024 block numbers can be stored in a block.

But in the inode, there are seven direct blocks which are (usually) used first. All files with a size of < 28 kiB only use the direct blocks.

Once the direct blocks are used up, one block is allocated and assigned to this inode as a list of block numbers which can be stored.

Answer (score 0):

32-bit block numbers means, it takes 32 bits or 4 bytes to store the address( or pointer) to the indirect block. If each address of the block takes 4 bytes, and each block has a capacity of 4KB (4 * 1024 bytes), each indirect block can store 1024 addresses(or pointers). Including the 7 direct pointers, there would be 1031 pointers to data blocks. Since each data block has a capacity of 4KB, the largest file that can be supported would be 1031 * 4KB.